# Set onclick event in loop while creating elements

Tags: javascript

I don't want to use jQuery, or any other 3rd party library!

Not working proof of concept:

```
<div id="Wrapper"></div>
<script>
    function Build()
{
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        var elem = document.createElement("div");
        elem.setAttribute("onclick", "OnClickEvent(" + i + ")");
        elem.textContent = "Hi";
        document.getElementById("Wrapper").appendChild(elem);
    }
}
function OnClickEvent(elementNum)
{
    alert("Hi! I am " + elementNum);
}

Build();
</script>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qyzrQ/

In real life:
I'm dynamically creating a table based on ajax callback, each row contains an image button and another table. This image button should be able to hide or show corresponding inner table.

Comment: I did forgot to add: I want to be able to add this onclick event before I'm adding new element to document tree. It is because i'm creating a whole structure, than I'm inserting it to the document.

Applying onclick event after inserting it to the document would force me to divide creation of this element into two places (and I would have to iterate whole table again, which i really don't want to do).

Comment: Can you post some html showing what you want it to look like and what elements you want listeners on?

Answer (score 0):

Frustrating. I was able to solve it myself.

It is enough to add (even before inserrting it into DOM):

```
element.setAttribute("onclick","functionName("+param+")");
```

Here is what i wanted to get: http://jsfiddle.net/YhY4Q/6/

And prototype (in case fiddle got deleted):

html:

```
<section id="Table" class="table">
    <header class="row">
        <div class="cell">header</div>
    </header>
    <script>
        function ToggleShow(id) {
            var elem = document.getElementById(id);
            if (elem.classList.contains("invisible")) {
                elem.classList.remove("invisible");
            } else {
                elem.classList.add("invisible");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <section id="TableWrapper">
    </section>
</section>
```

javascript:

```
function ToggleShow(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elem.classList.contains("invisible")) {
        elem.classList.remove("invisible");
    } else {
        elem.classList.add("invisible");
    }
}

function Build() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("TableWrapper");
    for (var id = 0; id < 10; id++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        row.appendChild(HeaderRowBuilder(id));
        row.appendChild(InnerTableBuilder(id));
        parent.appendChild(row);
    }
}

function HeaderRowBuilder(id) {
    var header = document.createElement("header");
    header.classList.add("row");
    header.appendChild(HeaderCellBuilder(id));
    var strongEle = document.createElement("strong");
    strongEle.classList.add("cell");
    strongEle.classList.add("cell2");
    strongEle.textContent = "Something else";
    header.appendChild(strongEle);
    return header;
}

function HeaderCellBuilder(id) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("cell");
    div.appendChild(HeaderImageBuilder(id));
    return div;
}

function HeaderImageBuilder(id) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("alt", "extended");
    img.setAttribute("onclick", "ToggleShow('InnerTable_" + id + "')");
    return img;
}

function InnerTableBuilder(id) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("id", "InnerTable_" + id);
    div.textContent = "More rows, I don't care about them right now";
    return div;
}

Build();
```

and css:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}
.table .cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
.table .cell2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}
.table .spacer {
    min-width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
}
.table .cell3 {
    min-width: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
}
.table .row {
    display: table-row;
}
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```